# in a while loop how do you hold data so that when the loop ends it will output all data inputed and not just reset on the next while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
bottles = [] 

while True:

    option = str(input('which option would you like?'))
    howmany = int(input('how many would you like?'))
    tax = float(.06)
    

    if option == '1':
      bottles = [int(howmany) for _ in range(howmany)]
     # Multiply each value in bottle by 0.1 & print the sum
      total = (sum([(b*.99) for b in bottles]))
      print((total*tax)+total)
    
    elif option == '2':
      bottles = [int(howmany) for _ in range(howmany)]
     # Multiply each value in bottle by 0.1 & print the sum
      total = (sum([(b*.79) for b in bottles]))
      print((total*tax)+total)

    elif option == '3':
      bottles = [int(howmany) for _ in range(howmany)]
     # Multiply each value in bottle by 0.1 & print the sum
      total = (sum([(b*1.09) for b in bottles]))
      print((total*tax)+total)
```

im trying to make it so this command acts like a group ordering dinner. if there is two people in the group it will take in those two inputs and them print both together. to specify how many people in the group is just how many times the loop runs. hope this makes sense

#code

```
 quitoption = str(input('would you like to contiune? yes or quit '))

    if quitoption == 'quit':
        print('thank you we will have your order right up')
        quit()

    else: print("contiune")
```

Comment: you store the results in a list usually

Comment: BTW< you do not need to say `int(howmany)` -- the result of `range` is always an int.  Also, the whole range/sum thing is wrong.  If they enter 5 bottles, you're going to sum up [1,2,3,4,5] and charge them for 15 bottles.  You just need `total = b*.99`.

Comment: You don't need to put the argument to `sum()` in a list. It will sum any sequence, so you can just use the generator directly.

Comment: You also don't need to call *str()* on the return value from *input()* as it's already a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem properly and your problem is that when while loop ends working list `bottles` is not you wish it to be
then it's maybe because you rewrite variable `bottle` 3 times each while loop iteration instead of adding anything to it 
so instead of this `bottles = [int(howmany) for _ in range(howmany)]` you'd try something like this `for _ in range(howmany): bottles.append(int(howmany))`

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are trying to do:

```
bottles = [] 
tax = float(.06)
total = 0

while True:
    option = input('which option would you like? ')
    if option == '0':
        break

    howmany = int(input('how many would you like? '))
    option = int(option)
    bottles.extend( [option] * howmany )
    
    if option == 1:
        total += howmany * .99
    
    elif option == 2:
        total += howmany * .79

    elif option == 3:
        total += howmany * 1.09

print( "You ordered these bottles:", bottles )
print( "Total before tax:", total )
print( "Total after tax:", total * (1+tax))
```

Output:

```
which option would you like? 1
how many would you like? 5
which option would you like? 2
how many would you like? 3
which option would you like? 3
how many would you like? 2
which option would you like? 0
You ordered these bottles: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
Total before tax: 9.5
Total after tax: 10.07
```